# no entiendo esta ruta del archivo web.php

Tags: laravel

lo que entiendo que esta pasando un parametro

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'ApplicationController')->where('any', '.*');
```

pero el controlador no lo esta pcupando

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ApplicationController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return view('application');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es una ruta que captura cualquier cosa que escribas en la URL. En inglés es un *catch-all*. Posteriormente, se muestra una vista, y en este caso no importa el parámetro, porque la idea es capturar todo lo que se escriba en la URL, o en otras palabras, nunca mostrar un error 404.

Voy a intentar explicar lo más detallado posible:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'ApplicationController')
```

Aquí estamos capturando un parámetro «obligatorio», y dicho parámetro lo llamamos «any».

Teniendo en cuenta que nuestro controlador solo realiza una acción específica, lo definimos por medio del método __invoke, por lo cual no es necesario escribir el nombre del método en la ruta.

```
->where('any', '.*');
```

Esto es una expresión regular, que captura cualquier cosa que escribas en la ruta, es algo como "donde el valor de any sea cualquier cosa".

Ya en el método del controlador, simplemente mostramos una vista, llamada 'application'.